# Select only the most recent line of a table based on a field

Tags: mysql

Given the following table:

```
Column1   Column2        Column3
Name1     "2016-05-11"   Value1
Name2     "2016-05-11"   Value2
Name2     "2015-05-17"   Value3
Name3     "2014-07-31"   Value4
Name4     "2011-07-31"   Value5
Name4     "2013-07-31"   Value6
Name4     "2016-09-31"   Value7
```

How do I select only the most recent value from Column2 for each Column1 value.
So the query result would be this:

```
Column1   Column2        Column3
Name1     "2016-05-11"   Value1
Name2     "2016-05-11"   Value2
Name3     "2014-07-31"   Value4
Name4     "2016-09-31"   Value7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a where in and a select max group by

```
select column1, column2, column3
from my_table 
where ( column1, column2 ) in 
          (select column1, max(column2)
                from my_table
                group by column1);
```

Comment: @Strawberry   the OP column2 seems a string containing date ..